# What is a template/

Tags: templates

Questioners keep using the word "template" which I don't understand in relation to LaTeX. The following is a well acknowledged definition of "template".

[image]

I don't see that any of these definitions have any revelance to the useage of "template" in the questions. It really throws me off about what the question is concerned with.

Perhaps "example" would be better than "template".

Peter W. --- GOM

Comment: It would be a lot better but overleaf and other sites use "template" it means (at overleaf) more or less an editable example that makes a complete document that you can edit to have whatever words you want in your actual document. That is teh second of your three bullet points

Comment: A model to copy also fits.